# Run a console app in Azure and see the console output

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I want to run a console application and see the output. It's a continuous one; I don't understand the other one.

I've got VisualStudio to deploy a console app to a WebJob, but I absolutely cannot get any output from it.

EDIT: why does the app service get a URL to 'browse' it? It's not a website.

EDIT: under HostingPlan->AppService->Diagnostic settings if I try to create a new *diagnostic settings* then there is a checkbox called `AppServiceConsoleLogs` which sounds promising, but it seems to require an *Archive to storage account* and none is listed even though I've set on up.

Comment: Two hours spent not being able to run a simple console application is pretty disappointing.

Looks like I'll stick to the 15 year old laptop for running it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really published this as a "WebJob," then go to the "WebJobs" section of your AppService -- it's in the Settings section -- and it should display your WebJob in the list.  Then right-click on your job and select "Logs."  This will open the logs for your job.  Click on the "Toggle Output" button and this should show you anything your app wrote to the console.

Edit:

Here is the WebJobs section of an App Service on the Azure Portal.  If you Right-click on a specific job, it will show a (non-browser) context menu that gives you access to Logs.
[image]

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, these options are via teh Azure Portal, not directly through Visual Studio.  I didn't realize that you were trying to do everything only from VS.  And an Azure WebJob DOES run under the context of an App Service.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create.  Quoting the first paragraph: "WebJobs is a feature of Azure App Service that enables you to run a program or script in the same context as a web app".  I run a ton of WebJobs and I assure that they are part of App Service.

Comment: I can see the stuff it creates on the Azure website but it's all very confusing.

Comment: It looks infeasible anyway: the free account is limited to an hour per day, and you seem to have to pay for something else that it won't work without.

Specifically, I'm running my .NET Core console app and SQL Express on an old laptop with a 4G SIM in an old phone. It's costing about £5 per month. I do not believe that Azure can match that.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough, if it doesn't meet your needs, that's cool. I was just trying to answer your question and (I assume) you downvoted me not because I was wrong, but because Azure isn't a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a subscription to Azure DevOps, you will be able to run your console app. Upload your console app and create a pipeline to run a script. Add the command and necessary arguments if any and run the pipeline.

The process may take around 10~15 minutes if you do not have an account with azure DevOps, and less if you have it already. Please follow the steps mentioned in the blog I wrote here and you should be able to run your console app without trouble.

[How to run Console Applications on Azure Pipelines](https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/)

PS: This may not be the best solution but as of now it offers free run of console apps on Azure Pipelines. Hope this helps!

Comment: Container instances are much cheaper; can they run a console application?

Comment: DevOps in this case. It's free. Container Instances supoort console app but with minimal charge. Choice is yours :-)

Comment: Actually a container instance seems to be about £15 per month -- so not cheap at all. The pricing is very difficult to work out.
My old laptop is costing £5 per month for a data sim.

Comment: Did you try running on Azure Pipelines? Try the schedule trigger and you can reduce the expenses down to zero!

Answer (score 0):

> why does the app service get a URL to 'browse' it?

Suppose it's your azure web url cause webjob is host in a web, if not please provide more information.

> it seems to require an Archive to storage account and none is listed
>   even though I've set on up.

Mostly it's because your storage account region is different from your web region, so create a new account with the same region then it will show in the list.

And suppose you want to check the webjob output, the simplest way is the Bryan Lewis way, just check the Logs in the kudu page. Else if you want to save it to storage and view it, go to **App Service logs** under your web `Monitoring`, set the `Application Logging (Blob)` and set the storage account(remember the region should be same or create a new one). Then you will be able to view the log csv file like below.

[image]

Comment: Can that run an application that runs in `while(true){ /* do stuff */}`? Or can it be triggered every minute like a cron job?

Comment: Yes, you could, and if you want to trigger it every minute, you could set it with [timer trigger webjob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger) but continuous or trigger one with [schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON).

Comment: Given up with the console app and using a Function instead.

It's unclear what it will cost.